# how to make variable "?" in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request

I want to make parameters as below

for example

```
http://localhost/firecek_web/pengaduan?barcode=8571385
```

route

```
Route::get('/pengaduan','PengaduanController@index');
```

Comment: Do you have form or are you inputting the parameters manually?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? How would you want to do it?

Comment: I want to take a barcode variable and make it a parameter

Comment: There's multiple way to do what you want but I think your question is too broad and your example is so simple that we can't have an idea on what exactly you want to do. That route is already work even if you put `?` request parameter in your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change your route definition. Just leave it as it stands:

```
Route::get('/pengaduan', 'PengaduanController@index');
```

Then, just append it to your url when making the request (just as you put it in your description):

```
http://localhost/firecek_web/pengaduan?barcode=8571385
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And then in your controller:

**PengaduanController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->query('barcode');
    // this also works:
    $value = $request->get('barcode');
    // or even this:
    $value = $request->barcode;

    dd($value); // '8571385'
}
```

Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input) of the documentation:

> ### Retrieving Input From The Query String
>
> While the `input` method retrieves values from entire request payload
>   (including the query string), the `query` method will only retrieve
>   values from the query string:
>
> ```
> $name = $request->query('name');
> ```
>
> If the requested query string value data is not present, the second
>   argument to this method will be returned:
>
> ```
> $name = $request->query('name', 'Helen');
> ```
>
> You may call the `query` method without any arguments in order to
>   retrieve all of the query string values as an associative array:
>
> ```
> $query = $request->query();
> ```